# How to call Sybase statistics commands using JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I want to invoke the update stats command on Sybase from Java. The JDBC shall give me status whether it was executed, or with the error code stating the problem. Which JDBC API shall I use on Statement to do this?

Also, does it supports rollback, if some error occurs in executing these commands?

For example: I execute update stats on 2 tables on 1 database in a transaction. If update stats on table 2 fails, will it rollback the update statts on table 1?

Here is the syntax for the update statistics in Sybase:

```
update statistics table_name
[[ partition data_partition_name ] [ (column_list ) ] |
index_name [ partition index_partition_name ] ] 
[ using step values ]
[ with consumers = consumers] [, sampling=percent]

update index statistics
table_name [[ partition data_partition_name ] |
[ index_name [ partition index_partition_name ] ] ]
[ using step values ]
[ with consumers = consumers] [, sampling=percent]

update all statistics table_name
[ partition data_partition_name ]
[ sp_configure histogram tuning factor, <value>

update table statistics
table_name [partition data_partition_name ]

delete [ shared ] statistics table_name
[ partition data_partition_name ] 
[( column_name[, column_name ] ...)]
```

Any help on this or some pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE STATISTICS (in its various flavours) can indeed be rolled back. But there is really no good reason why you would want to do that. Worst case, you end up keeping resource allocated that don't need to be.

Just check the @@error status for the result of the stmt.

As for which flavour of UPDATE STATISTICS to use, that is an entirely different discussion. See the ASE Performance & Tuning Guide for guidance on this.